# How tight does vent screen have to be, to keep out swarming termites?

Tags: vent, pest-control, termite

So I found some winged "ants" on my roof. My roof and crawl spaces have vents with 1/4 inch wire mesh, very easy for such "ants" to get into.

Of course, they were not ants, they were swarmer termites.  In this case they came from outside the house.  And I happen to know they were drywoods.  That said:

[image: Wire Mesh to Keep Out Termites]

What size mesh is needed to keep out swarmers, without blocking too much ventillation? If you answer, what's your source for the information?

Answer (score 1):

Ants have a narrow body in the middle, termites have a solid body. It would take a fine mesh like screen doors to keep both critters out. 1/4" can let even wasps and other bees in.